# Comparing char values in two different arrays

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have to compare two arrays that each have 444 chars in them, and if they are the exact same, output that they are identical. If they aren't then the program would continue until it is done comparing all the arrays to each other.

This is my code so far. I have changed it several times but I either get the program to output nothing to the outFile (saying none are identical which I find to be wrong since I would imagine one would be identical or the prof. wouldn't ask us to do this) or it says that every gene strand is identical:

```
#include iostream
#include string
#include fstream
using namespace std;

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;


bool SameGene(char gene1[], char gene2[], int size)

{
    for(int i=0, j=0;i<444 && j<444;i++,j++)
        if(gene1[i] != gene2[j])
            return false;

    return true;
}


int main()
{

    inFile.open("dna.txt");
    outFile.open("DNAanalysis.txt.");

    char gene1A[444], gene2A[444];

    char gene1B[444], gene2B[444];

    char gene1C[444], gene2C[444];

    char gene1D[444], gene2D[444];

    inFile.read(gene1A, 444);
    inFile.read(gene2A, 444);
    inFile.read(gene1B, 444);
    inFile.read(gene2B, 444);
    inFile.read(gene1C, 444);
    inFile.read(gene2C, 444);
    inFile.read(gene1D, 444);
    inFile.read(gene2D, 444);

    if(SameGene(gene1A, gene1B, 444) || SameGene(gene2A, gene2B, 444))
        outFile << "Person A and Person B are related." << endl;
    if(SameGene(gene1A, gene1C, 444) || SameGene(gene2A, gene2C, 444))
        outFile << "Person A and Person C are related." << endl;
    if(SameGene(gene1A, gene1D, 444) || SameGene(gene2A, gene2D, 444))
        outFile << "Person A and Person D are related." << endl;
    if(SameGene(gene1B, gene1C, 444) || SameGene(gene2B, gene2C, 444))
        outFile << "Person B and Person C are related." << endl;
    if(SameGene(gene1B, gene1D, 444) || SameGene(gene2B, gene2D, 444))
        outFile << "Person B and Person D are related." << endl;
    if(SameGene(gene1C, gene1D, 444) || SameGene(gene2C, gene2D, 444))
        outFile << "Person C and Person D are related." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) to compare two arrays:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool same = std::equal(gene1, gene1+444, gene2);
```

Here you have to make sure `gene2` is at least as long as `gene1`.

If your problem lies elsewhere, then you should make this clear in the question's title and focus on the real problem.

Comment: Well I know each is the same length as I was given the input file. I just need to make sure all 444 chars are or are not the same in each array. If gene1A[1] = A and gene1B[1] = B, my question is answered instantly since all 444 would need to be the same.

Comment: @TannerRoss OK, then the code snippet above should do the trick. It will return false at the first negative comparison.

Comment: And I would add that inside the subfunction SameGene?

Comment: @TannerRoss You could replace the code in `SameGene` for this. But I would just replace your function entirely. It isn't much longer.

Comment: That was the one detail I know I did seem to not add. Instructions from professor specifically state I must use a subfunction "SameGene" to determine if the genes are identical.

Comment: Arbitrary "requirements"! Excellent!

Comment: @TannerRoss OK, then maybe you should specify the requirements. If this is an assignment, it might be disallowed to use `std::equal` in the first place.